# Achievette: move token? (Imaginarium expansion Chimera)

Tags: imaginarium, imaginarium-chimera

### Overview

I have a rules question in the Imaginarium expansion "Chimera".

There are two parts of the rules which I *think* I understand how they combine, but I'm not 100% sure.

[Rules for Chimera found here](https://cdn.1j1ju.com/medias/56/f8/61-imaginarium-chimera-rulebook.pdf)

### Rules

Part 1: Rules for 'daydreaming' (pages 7-8). This is the only place in the rulebook I found which explicitly says I can move my token down the dream track. It is step 2 of daydream action.

> 2. Move forward on the dream track
>
> Each dream fragment thus placed moves you one space forward on the dream track. You move an additional space for each fragment of the same color as the last placed, if they follow directly (see example below).
>
> When you pass or stop first on a space containing resources, charcoalium or victory points, take them and place them behind your screen. The other players, who pass this space after you, will only receive one charcoalium (even if this space contains something other than charcoalium during setup). Different paths are possible, choose well!

Part 2: Rules for 'Achievette' (page 15 bottom).

> The Achievette (S4) allows you each turn, during the phase of using the machines, to add a dream fragment from behind your screen to your dream. If you don’t have a dream fragment to place, the Achievette has no effect.
>
> A single Achievette enables you to place 1 dream fragment per turn.
>
> Two combined Achievette enable you to place up to 3 dream fragments of
> different colors per turn.
>
> Combinable with: Achievette.

### Interpretation

I assume that means that when I start my turn (Implementation phase), I can place a dream fragment, but I do **not** get to move my token on the dream track. However, it's still helpful to get an extra placement in the same turn, because then I can

1. make sure my last fragment is not a nightmare anymore (if someone played nightmare on me). Thus, I effectively negate that penalty
2. It allows me to chain multiple fragments of the same color on the same turn.

### Question

Is that really the intent of the creator of the game do we think? Should I assume that the achievette actually lets me move my token an additional time that turn too?